# Generating a dataframe from a groupby transformation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this code:

```
df.droupby('type)['feature1].mean()
```

`df` has 15 `features` from `1 to 15`

I want to iterate over a list of the features names and append these 15 results in a dataframe:

**Desired Output: type(dataframe)**

```
    type      feature1       features2  ..... feature15
    type_A    mean(float)    mean(float)      mean(float)
    type_B    mean(float)    mean(float)      mean(float)
    type_c    mean(float)    mean(float)      mean(float)
```

**What I did:**

I have the list of features:

```
list = df.iloc[:, 10:24].columns.to_list()
```

and tried something like this:

```
for i in len(list):
    df.groupby('type')[list[i]].mean()
```

to see if I get something and this line returns an error:

```
'int' object is not iterable
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you able to provide a sample of your dataframe and expected output? That would make it a ton easier to come up with a fast solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could simply use `groupby` + `mean`:

```
out = df.groupby('type', as_index=False).mean()
```

But if you have a bunch of other columns that you don't want to include in the calculation and only want the mean of "feature..." columns, you could `filter`, then `groupby` + `mean`:

```
out = df.filter(like='feature').groupby(df['type']).mean().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  type  feature1  feature2
0    A      10.0      11.0
1    B      12.0      14.0
2    C      13.0      13.0
3    D      12.0      19.0
4    E      10.0      10.0
```